# mouseup-event doesn't trigger during dragging

Tags: javascript, html, html5-draggable

I drag one element over another and I want the other element to change when I let go of the drag. But the 'mouseup' event doesn't work when the mouse on the same time lets go of a dragged object. What can I do?

my html-list:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">1</li>
  <li  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">2</li>
</ul>
```

The EventListener:

```
here.addEventListener("dragover", display, false);
```

The insert function:

```
function display(evt) {
var clicked =  evt.target;
var newItem = document.createElement('li');
newItem.innerHTML=clicked.innerHTML;
insertAfter(newItem, clicked);}
```

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: https://codepen.io/JulianLaub/pen/RpvwLP

Comment: are you getting it?

Comment: where is you `drag` function defined?

Comment: I am thinking of leaving this all together and using library with angular - do you know if list configuration in vanilla js will bring me to my knees?

Comment: check this one https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists

Comment: yeah, sth like that. I am using a mysql library sofar to make sure the resulsts are save. I will then create account for other users to manage their lists. Is that also doable with a library?

Comment: I don't know, see the  docs for it